# Visual Basic DataRow/DataSet/DataGrid change specific cell text color

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

```
For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                    If (row("Flag") And 1 = 1) Then
                        row("Col_1") = Color.Red
                    End If
                    If (row("Flag") And 2 = 2) Then
                        row("Col_2") = Color.Red
                    End If
                    If (row("Flag") And 4 = 4) Then
                        row("Col_3") = Color.Red
                    End If
                    If (row("Flag") And 8 = 8) Then
                        row("Col_4") = Color.Red
                    End If
                Next
```

I would like to set a specific cell to red based on a flag. I have access to a DataSet and DataGrid, but not DataGridView. Is there a simple way to accomplish this with DataGrid? I believe what I have now doesn't work as the DataRow is just memory data.

Comment: Yea it's vb.net, my bad

Comment: put `row("Col_1") = Color.Red` before any of the `If` statements just to see if the cells would ever get colored.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using `1=1` , just use `True`   ... wait a minute

looking at your code again ... you are doing bit manipulation ... i think that you are missing some brackets in your if statements

should be `If ((row("Flag") And 1) = 1) Then`  .... same for the rest

Comment: I changed to using DataGridItem in the ForEach since DataGrid.Item is a DataGridItem. The Cells object has a ForeColor which I will use to set the color to red, and I'm using CInt to cast the Text object of Cells